# how to navigate the particular pivot item in windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my windows application, I am using 4 pivot items for example cash,change password, items,profile. whenever i click the any pivot item the page navigate to profile pivot item only. But i need to go to particular pivot item only. Please any one help me out.

code:

```
private void changepassword_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile), uuid);
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile));
        }
```

Comment: please any one help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate with pivot tab index as parameter

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile), 1)
```

In your profile page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MainPivot.SelectedIndex = (int) e.Parameter;
}
```