# how will navigate to required pivot item?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my windows phone application one profile page is there.in this profile page profile,changepassword,orders and cash pivot items are there.

Whenever I click `changepasswordbutton` then page will  navigate from mainpage to profile page always go to profile pivot item only.

I want to go to changepassword pivotitem. How will solve this problem? please help me....

```
  private void changepassword_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered by stack overflow for this question

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300984/how-to-navigate-the-particular-pivot-item-in-windows)

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(profile), 1);
```

In your profile page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MainPivot.SelectedIndex = (int) e.Parameter;
}
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

You can set the pivot control's `SelectedIndex` property to switch to a distinct pivot item within the page. For example, if *changepassword* is the third pivot item, you'd set

```
PivotControl.SelectedIndex = 2
```

If this shall be done directly after loading the page (e.g. because you just navigated to the page containing the pivot control), I'd run this code within the page's `OnNavigatedTo` method.